# Loading from cloned ext4 partition

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, external-hdd, clonezilla

I decided to clone my bootable Linux partition to an USB HDD. I splitted that drive into partitions and made full copy using Clonezilla [as follows there](http://clonezilla.org/liveusb.php).
However, when I try to boot from an external HDD, **loader still *thinks* that it is situated on the previous drive.**
Here is a part of `sudo fdisk -l` to make it clearer. This is the internal drive and its partition with source system:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 698,7 GiB, 750156374016 bytes, 1465149168 sectors
...
/dev/sda5            2048   97656344   97654297  46,6G 83 Linux
```

And this is the external one and cloned partition:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
...
/dev/sdb2       140656640 976773119 836116480 398,7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

What I already did is:

- Found out that there is no loader on external drive, and did `grub-upgrade` while being in `chroot` mode on mounted device.
  Then, it allowed me to boot from `sdb1`, but
- Also found out that when grub2 starts to load Linux kernel (and doing this from `(msdos1,0)` drive), still it **uses `sda5` drive**, which leads me to load internal Linux partition.
- I found that after Clonezilla cloned the partition, its UUID was remained the same. So, I changed it using `tune2fs` tool.
- After all I changed `/etc/fstab` on internal drive, made it bootable using `parted` and did `grub-upgrade` again, which has no effect at all.

So what is the way to start using external cloned partition and Linux installed on it? Any help appreciated.